# How to display Asctime as a visual graph

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a code that can log my keystrokes and display a each press in representation of a graph. however when ever I attempt to run the code through the matplotlib i get the error of string can't be converted into a float

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np

```
x, y = np.loadtxt('key_log.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Display the information taken from using asctime command to display time and amount of strokes displayed as a graph

Comment: are you sure the delimiter is `,` try `;`... it is used by some csv generators, can you print `x`&`y` and tell us what it looks like. Without more information about the structure of your data, it will be difficult to answer.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte I've changed the delimiter and I'm coming up with a different error but I think i'm on track, I can't print the x or y value but i can show you the value error that flags when running the code.   ( ValueError: could not convert string to float: '["2018-10-17 22:27:23,224", "\'h\'"]')

Comment: Ah, ok, try `import csv; f = csv.reader("file.txt", delimiter = ';'); print([ i for i in f])` At least you will have an idea of what the correct delimiter is and why some values aren't numbers. You can then filter the array yourself before giving It to `numpy`

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte thank you for your help, starting to understand it a bit more now

Comment: If you want to plot time, I would highly suggest using the `datetime` module, or convert your dates & times to `epoch` time. Computers prefer handling integers.

Comment: is there a way i could get a bit more guidance on this im not sure where to use the datatime function in regards to the x & y axis, could i potentially email you or something ?

Comment: Not on this thread, you can ask questions if you have one, but it is probably already answered, `help(datetime.datetime) and dir(datetime.datetime)` is a good start. Google is your friend, read the doc, and Good luck.